# listview is not refreshing values after deleting row with checkbox value = true

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, baseadapter, notifydatasetchanged

Good day,

I'm doing a listview, baseadapter with checkbox that is able to delete multiple selected rows.

here is my onCreate :

```
 ArrayList<Memos> list;

 list = new ArrayList<Memos>();
 list.add(new Memos(1, "s", "s"));
 list.add(new Memos(2, "x", "aaa"));
 list.add(new Memos(3, "v", "aesf"));

 final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
 lv.setAdapter(new MemoListAdapter(list, this));

 deletebutton
 @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
           MemoListAdapter myAdapter = (MemoListAdapter)lv.getAdapter();  
           myAdapter.remove();
      }
```

then here is my complete baseadapter :

```
        public class MemoListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Memos> listComment;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private ArrayList<Memos> deleteMemos;

    public MemoListAdapter(List<Memos> listComment, Context context) {
        super();
        this.listComment = listComment;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        deleteMemos = new ArrayList<Memos>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return listComment.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Memos getItem(int position) {
        return listComment.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {

     return getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

     return position;
    }

    public class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView body;
        TextView date;
        CheckBox checkBox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {   
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.body = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.big_text);
            holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.small_text);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            holder.body.setText(listComment.get(position).getMessageBody());
            holder.date.setText(listComment.get(position).getMessageDate());

            holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                          //is chkIos checked?
                    if(listComment.get(position).isCheckbox()) {
                     holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
                     deleteMemos.remove(listComment.get(position));
                    }
                    else {
                        // Do invisible or gone stuff here
                     holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
                     deleteMemos.add(listComment.get(position));
                    }

                }
              });
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    public void remove() {

        for(Memos memo : deleteMemos) {
            listComment.remove(memo);
        }
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    }
```

after selecting rows to delete (4 rows)

[image]

the list adjusted but the contents and the check value of the checkbox is still the same.

[image]

I am wondering what part of the notifyDataSetChanged is wrong.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Move your `this.notifyDataSetChanged();` below `listComment.remove(memo);`, inside for loop.

Comment: @Stanojkovic, sadly, it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your views are reused that's why it happen . Try adding below codes into your getView()

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.body = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.big_text);
            holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.small_text);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if(listComment.get(position).isCheckbox()) {
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
        }else {
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
        }

        holder.body.setText(listComment.get(position).getMessageBody());


        holder.date.setText(listComment.get(position).getMessageDate());
        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked)  {
                listComment.get(position).setIsCheckbox(isChecked);
                if (isChecked){
                    deleteMemos.add(listComment.get(position));
                }else{
                    deleteMemos.remove(listComment.get(position));
                }
            }

        });

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: sadly, it doesn't work :(
the checkbox do reset... but the listrow only adjust and doesn't remove the correct item that is deleted. :(

Comment: yeah, It is now working perfectly!
thank you very mucH!